# Having objects unwrapped in the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am `console.log`ing some JSON and Google Chrome by default has the whole object wrapped. So if I want to have a global view of the stuff in the JSON, I have to manually unwrap every property reccursively. Is it possible to tell `console.log` that I want my object to be completely unwrapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.dir` and `console.log` wrap objects in that manner so they don't have to deal with recursion, which would cause an infinite loop.  I don't believe there's a way to have it unwrap the entire object (for the aforementioned reason) with a special command.

You could restringify the JSON to be "pretty" and view the entire thing as a string:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(compressedJSON), null, 4));
```

The only other option is to paste your JSON into a JSON viewing application ([Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) has one built in).

Comment: Thanks! What about unwrapping to a certain level of precision, to avoid the infinite recursion problem?

Comment: @Randomblue: nope, I don't believe it's possible.